# how much gas does an erroneous transaction consume?

Tags: go-ethereum

Lets say, a transaction produced an error, for example, r,s,v fields are invalid. Will this transaction use the gas?

Looking at the sources, I see that it doesn't, it returns `nil` in consumed gas on error (third line, after tx.AsMessage() fails), but after doing some tests, I see it consumed the gas limit on the account balance in the statedb, so it isn't clear for me how much gas does an invalid transaction take (or should take)?

```
// ApplyTransaction attempts to apply a transaction to the given state database
// and uses the input parameters for its environment. It returns the receipt
// for the transaction, gas used and an error if the transaction failed,
// indicating the block was invalid.
func ApplyTransaction(config *params.ChainConfig, bc *BlockChain, author *common.Address, gp *GasPool, statedb *state.StateDB, header *types.Header, tx *types.Transaction, usedGas *big.Int, cfg vm.Config) (*types.Receipt, *big.Int, error) {
    msg, err := tx.AsMessage(types.MakeSigner(config, header.Number))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    // Create a new context to be used in the EVM environment
    context := NewEVMContext(msg, header, bc, author)
    // Create a new environment which holds all relevant information
    // about the transaction and calling mechanisms.
    vmenv := vm.NewEVM(context, statedb, config, cfg)
    // Apply the transaction to the current state (included in the env)
    _, gas, failed, err := ApplyMessage(vmenv, msg, gp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    // Update the state with pending changes
    var root []byte
    if config.IsByzantium(header.Number) {
        statedb.Finalise(true)
    } else {
        root = statedb.IntermediateRoot(config.IsEIP158(header.Number)).Bytes()
    }
    usedGas.Add(usedGas, gas)

    // Create a new receipt for the transaction, storing the intermediate root and gas used by the tx
    // based on the eip phase, we're passing wether the root touch-delete accounts.
    receipt := types.NewReceipt(root, failed, usedGas)
    receipt.TxHash = tx.Hash()
    receipt.GasUsed = new(big.Int).Set(gas)
    // if the transaction created a contract, store the creation address in the receipt.
    if msg.To() == nil {
        receipt.ContractAddress = crypto.CreateAddress(vmenv.Context.Origin, tx.Nonce())
    }

    // Set the receipt logs and create a bloom for filtering
    receipt.Logs = statedb.GetLogs(tx.Hash())
    receipt.Bloom = types.CreateBloom(types.Receipts{receipt})

    return receipt, gas, err
}
```

Comment: What does "r,s,v fields do not match the real signature" mean? What's the "real signature" if not the r, s, and v fields of the transaction?

Comment: I mean, the signature is not authentic, when the private key is not the real one (forged transaction, for example)

Comment: What is "the real one?" The way you know who sent a transaction is by looking at the signature and recovering a public key (and then account) from it. By definition, whatever account the signature indicates is "the real one."

Comment: @smarx ok, but some combination of r,s,v values can produce invalid transaction message , what happens in this case? is the gas used or not?

Comment: If no address can be recovered, then how could gas be used? (What account would you charge?)

Comment: @smarx, you are right, there can't be any TX fee charge, I found out that I was using wrong EIP155 config, on the wrong block number, that's why I saw the state modified in my tests